# How do I take one column of a Pandas dataframe and make it become part of the index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe which looks something like this:

```
                      data  day_of_month  days_in_month
timestamp
2022-01-03 09:00:00     12             3             31
```

There is currently an index, which has the type of "pandas timestamp".

I want to be able to index this dataframe by the value in the column "days_in_month".

One way to do this might be to split the dataframe into seperate dataframes, each one holding data for a different day of the month.

That would be relatively easy to do:

```
# etc ...
df_30_days_in_month = df[df['days_in_month'] == 30]
df_31_days_in_month = df[df['days_in_month'] == 31]
```

This isn't the route I want to take.

If I knew the name of the operation required to do this it would be relatively easy to search for a solution - but I don't.

I tried:

- pivot
- melt

neither of those appears to be the correct operation.

I want to keep `timestamp` as an index - but as a second level index. The primary index should be the `days_in_month` value.

What should I do?

Comment: plz provide enough example : [mre]

Comment: @PandaKim How exactly would you write a MWE for this. I **cannot** give you the dataset.

Comment: **Do you understand that the MRE announcement is not asking for your dataset?** It is asking you to create a few lines of example code with a sufficient amount of effort, and the desired output should be made into a text table.

Comment: @PandaKim I'm not wasting my time creating you fake data for something which doesn't need fake data. The answer turned out to be obvious. No data is required to know the answer to this question - you either know the answer or you don't. In your case you didn't know.

Answer (score 1):

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd
idx = pd.Index(['2022-01-03 09:00:00'], name='timestamp')
df = pd.DataFrame([[12, 3, 31]], index=idx, columns=['data', 'day_of_month', 'days_in_month'])
```

df

```
                     data  day_of_month  days_in_month
timestamp                                             
2022-01-03 09:00:00    12             3             31
```

**Code**

use `set_index` with append + `swaplevel`

```
out = df.set_index('days_in_month', append=True).swaplevel(0, 1)
```

out

```
                                   data  day_of_month
days_in_month timestamp                                       
31            2022-01-03 09:00:00    12             3
```

Answer (score -2):

There's two methods which are part of the Pandas dataframe which allow an index to be removed (put "back as a column") and another method which allows creation of a new index using the existing columns.

Here's how to use those functions.

```
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df.set_index(['days_in_month', 'timestamp'], inplace=True)
```